# Jazz Drumming - What is the drummer (Art Blakey) tapping on?

Tags: drums, jazz, drum-kits

If you listen to [Nica's Dream](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Lju13U1zEE&ab_channel=60otaku4/%22Nica's%20Dream%22) Art Blakey is tapping the cascara on something but I can't figure out what.

The tapping is right at the start of the video linked above.

It doesn't sound like the rim of the drum.

Does anyone know what is going on here?

Answer (score 2):

I could be wrong, but it sounds like he's tapping on a closed hi hat.

Comment: That's what I thought as well

Comment: I don't think so. If you listen at 7:30 in the youtube video, you hear him landing 2 and 4 chicks on the hi-hat while playing this pattern. If he was making this  noise with the hi-hat you would hear open hi-hat noise in between 2 and 4.